# Inserting before and after a node

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert

I have the two functions below and they do not change my linked list at all. I account for the fact that if the given node is null, I then check to see if the given node is the head or tail, and lastly I insert where needed and correct where the nodes are pointing. I must be missing a small part but I am not sure what. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
        // insert the new object after the node p
void DoublyLinkedList::insertAfter(DListNode &p, int newobj) {
    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Empty Doubly Linked List");
    }


    DListNode *newNode = new DListNode();
    newNode->obj = newobj;
    newNode->prev = &p;
    newNode->next = p.next;

    if (p.next != NULL) {
        p.next->prev = newNode;
    }

    p.next = newNode;


    if(&trailer == &p){
        trailer = *newNode;
    }
}


// insert the new object before the node p
void DoublyLinkedList::insertBefore(DListNode &p, int newobj){

    if(isEmpty()) {
        throw EmptyDLinkedListException("Empty Doubly Linked List");
    }


    DListNode *newNode = new DListNode();
    newNode->obj = newobj;
    newNode->prev = p.prev;
    newNode->next = &p;

    if(&header == &p){
         header = *newNode;

    }

    if (p.prev != NULL) {
        p.prev->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

[image: This shows the debugger for the insert after function]

I have a list that is originally:

```
100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

I then implement the insertAfter function to insert 15 after 80:

```
cout << "On list2 insert 15 after 80. " << endl;
DListNode location = *dll2.getFirst()->next->next;
dll2.insertAfter(location, 15);
cout << "list2: " << dll2 << endl << endl;
```

According to the debugger, everything is pointing in the correct place but the result from the above function call:

```
On list2 insert 15 after 80. 
list2: 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

The weird thing is that when I implement the insertAfter and then insertBefore like:

```
// add tests for insertAfter
    cout << "On list2 insert 15 after 80. " << endl;
    DListNode location = *dll2.getFirst()->next->next;
    dll2.insertAfter(location, 15);
    cout << "list2: " << dll2 << endl << endl;

    //insertBefore
    cout << "On list2 insert 9 before 80. " << endl;
    dll2.insertBefore(location, 9);
    cout << "list2: " << dll2 << endl << endl;
```

The ouput is this:

```
On list2 insert 15 after 80. 
list2: 100 90 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 

On list2 insert 9 before 80. 
list2: 100 90 9 80 15 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

which shows the 9 was inserted before and 15 was inserted after, but when the function is ending there is a segmentation fault in the destructor saying that the node being deleted was not allocated.

Comment: "if(&p == NULL) " - A pointer can be null, but the address of an object can never be null, and here `&p` is the address of an existing object.

Comment: ahh okay I will change the wording of my exception that is thrown. Thank you for that

Comment: Kate, generally, the way we find errors in our code is not by thinking about it real hard.  It is not even by showing the code to other folks who might be able to think even harder.  The way we find errors in our code is by using a debugger.  I suppose someone might show up eventually who will be able to point at the error in your code, but you would have saved yourself a lot of time (and learned a very valuable skill) if you just used your debugger.

Comment: and no, what Neil means is that you need to get rid of the entire `if()` statement together with the throwing of the exception.  It will never happen.

Comment: I have used my debugger and for the insertAfter function I am showing that everything is pointing in the right direction with the updated code.

Comment: I understand that when I insertAfter I will have to assign the prev and next nodes for newNode. I will also need to define the p next node to point at new Node and then p.next prev node to point at new node as well. I think it just may be the order in which I am doing this

Comment: please see my edits

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is a list of pointers. Your list's `header` and `trailer` fields need to be `DListNode*` pointers, not `DListNode` object instances.  They are useless to list management if they are not pointers.

Your code is not correctly updating the nodes that surround the `p` node.  Even if you have to update the `header` or `trailer` field, you still have to update other nodes, too.  But you are not doing that.

It is also not customary to pass around nodes by reference, but you are doing that anyway. I didn't want to say anything about that earlier, but you really should be passing them by pointer instead.

You code should look more like this:

```
private:
    DListNode *header, *trailer;

...

void DoublyLinkedList::insertAfter(DListNode *p, int newobj)
{
    DListNode *newNode = new DListNode();
    newNode->obj = newobj;
    newNode->prev = p;
    newNode->next = p->next;

    if (p->next != NULL) {
        p->next->prev = newNode;
    }

    p->next = newNode;

    if (trailer == p) {
        trailer = newNode;
    }
}

void DoublyLinkedList::insertBefore(DListNode *p, int newobj)
{
    DListNode *newNode = new DListNode();
    newNode->obj = newobj;
    newNode->prev = p->prev;
    newNode->next = p;

    if (p->prev != NULL) {
        p->prev->next = newNode;
    }

    if (header == p) {
        header = newNode;
    }
}
```

That being said, as I advised you in an earlier question, once you understand how double-linked lists work, you should throw away all of this code and just use the STL [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) class instead, which is a standard double-linked list implementation.

Comment: Your code is giving me the same issue as my original code. Here is another thing I have notice. I first call insertAfter and print the list and it is not changed. I then call insertBefore and print the list and the changes that should have occured after using insertAfter are now visible along with the insertBefore changes, but then I get a segmentation fault at the end with the destructor. I have used my debugger and it is not in the destructor but some issue with insertAfter and insertBefore

Comment: @Kate a linked list is a list of pointers, but you have not changed `header` and `trailer` to be pointers, like I told you to do. For a linked list implementation, this is very important. It is also not customary to pass around nodes by reference, but you are doing that anyway. I didn't want to say anything about that earlier, but you really should be passing them by pointer instead.